# Transposing row values into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

My Actual Table is like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Code  |   Name    |   PrevYear | NextYear | PrevYearQty    |   NextYearQty |]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A        Adapter    Jan13         Jan14     100                 110 
A        Adapter    Feb13         Feb14      50                  55
B        Baloon     Jan13         Jan14      30                  33
B        Baloon     Mar13         Mar14      80                  88
D        Deodrant   Feb13         Feb14     110                 121 
C        Camera     Mar13         Mar14     200                 220
```

And I want result like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code  |   Name    |   Jan13  | Jan14 | Feb13 |   Feb14 | Mar13 |  Mar14   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A        Adapter        100    110       -         -       -         - 
A        Adapter         -      -        50        55      -         -
B        Baloon          30     33       -         -       -         - 
B        Baloon          -       -       -         -      80        88
D        Deodrant        -       -       110       121     -         -
C        Camera          -       -       -         -       200     220
_______________________________________________________________________________
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried googling SQL PIVOT tables? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+server+pivot+example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TableName TABLE(Code CHAR(1), Name VARCHAR(10),PrevYear VARCHAR(10)
,NextYear VARCHAR(10), PrevYearQty INT, NextYearQty INT)
INSERT INTO @TableName VALUES
('A','Adapter' ,'Jan13','Jan14',100,110),('A','Adapter' ,'Feb13','Feb14',50 ,55),
('B','Baloon'  ,'Jan13','Jan14',30 ,33),('B','Baloon'  ,'Mar13','Mar14',80 ,88),
('D','Deodrant','Feb13','Feb14',110,121),('C','Camera'  ,'Mar13','Mar14',200,220)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT Code, Name, PrevYear AS Yr, PrevYearQty AS Qty FROM @TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT Code, Name, NextYear, NextYearQty FROM @TableName
)t
PIVOT (SUM(Qty)
       FOR Yr
       IN ([Jan13],[Jan14],[Feb13],[Feb14],[Mar13],[Mar14])
       )p
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ Code ║   Name   ║ Jan13 ║ Jan14 ║ Feb13 ║ Feb14 ║ Mar13 ║ Mar14 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ A    ║ Adapter  ║ 100   ║ 110   ║ 50    ║ 55    ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║
║ B    ║ Baloon   ║ 30    ║ 33    ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 80    ║ 88    ║
║ C    ║ Camera   ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 200   ║ 220   ║
║ D    ║ Deodrant ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║ 110   ║ 121   ║ NULL  ║ NULL  ║
╚══════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

If you want your query to pick the columns dynamically see here how would you go about doing that.

**Dynamic Query**

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + QUOTENAME(q.Yr)
                      FROM (
                       SELECT PrevYear AS Yr FROM TableName
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT NextYear FROM TableName
                       )q
                       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')


SET @Sql = N'SELECT Code, Name,  '+ @Cols +'
            FROM 
            (
            SELECT Code, Name, PrevYear AS Yr, PrevYearQty AS Qty FROM TableName
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Code, Name, NextYear, NextYearQty FROM TableName
            )t
            PIVOT (SUM(Qty)
                   FOR Yr
                   IN (' + @Cols + ')
                   )p'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: Thanks M.Ali but this query results to wrong data when row 1's nextyear is equal to the  row 2's prevyear 
row   prevyear     nextyear   prevyearrQTY  prevyearrQTY
1      apr12         apr13        200             20
2      apr13         apr14        100             10